# Cannot set property of undefined and no AMD

Tags: javascript

My js files are imported into one html file in a specific order. Here an example that my js files look like:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @namespace NS.MODULE
 */
(function (undefined) {
    var NS = NS || {};

    if (undefined === NS.MODULE) {
        NS.MODULE = {};
    }
})();

/**
 * Module to handle the search form
 *
 * @namespace form
 * @memberOf NS.MODULE
 *
 * @type {}
 */
NS.MODULE.form = (function ($, _, undefined) {
    // body ...
})(jQuery, _);
```

A very weird error shows up

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'form' of undefined

Is it normal that `NS.MODULE.form` gets executed before `undefined === NS.MODULE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NS is not in the global scope, you only define it in the scope of your iife. Try this:

```
window.NS = window.NS || {};

if (NS.MODULE === undefined) {
    NS.MODULE = {};
}
```